# How to encode swagger request in base64, in NodeJs, using express-swagger-generator npm

Tags: base64, swagger

I am using swagger, express-swagger-generator npm, have added jwt token using '@security JWT', now I need to receive the request in base64 from swagger I was unable to find it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue manually, I needed to encode my swagger request too in base64 so my swagger request and web request can be the same. So to make both on the same page, I made a middleware in my server.js file before it reaches to the route.

1. It checks if the request is from swagger, then encodes it in the base64 which can be decoded further.
2. To know the request-id from swagger you will have to save the swagger origin and once the request comes then check `request.origin == swagger_origin`
3. Why I did this? To encode my request and then again decode it, I could have checked if my request is from swagger then I won't decode it. But encoding the swagger request helps as if there is an error while decoding the request it will help me to find it locally just by using the swagger, independently won't need front-end to send the request again and again to check the issue